# Limit Wireguard client access to only a few servers

Tags: iptables, wireguard

I have a wireguard server that controls access to a network of servers in AWS. Clients connecting via wireguard have addresses 10.11.0.{2-5}. I have 4 clients that access the LAN with full access - the LAN is on 10.1.255.255. That works fine.

Now I want to add a client that will only have access to a small number of servers.

So I've added some PostUp commands in wg0.conf, and use iptables to limit this client to those servers.

[Note I prefer to use PostUp commands rather than a separate postup.sh file because it keeps customisations in one place.]

Below are the iptables commands. Clients 10.11.0.{2,3,4,5} should be able to access everything. Client 10.11.0.6 should only have access to three specific ip addresses. What is happening is that client .6 can still access everything.

```
PostUp = iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0  -j MASQUERADE -s 10.11.0.0/16

# Add a WIREGUARD_wg0 chain
PostUp = iptables -N WIREGUARD_wg0
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -j WIREGUARD_wg0

# Accept traffic from valid Wireguard client IP addresses
PostUp = iptables -A WIREGUARD_wg0 -s 10.11.0.2,10.11.0.3,10.11.0.4,10.11.0.5 -i %i -j ACCEPT
# This client can only access these servers.
PostUp = iptables -A WIREGUARD_wg0 -s 10.11.0.6 -i %i -d    10.1.1.101,10.1.1.151,10.1.0.101 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -A WIREGUARD_wg0 -s 10.11.0.6 -i %i -j DROP

# Drop everything else coming through the Wireguard interface
PostUp = iptables -A WIREGUARD_wg0 -i %i -j DROP

# Return to FORWARD chain
PostUp = iptables -A WIREGUARD_wg0 -j RETURN

PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0  -j MASQUERADE -s 10.11.0.0/16

# Flush and delete the WIREGUARD_wg0 chain
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -j WIREGUARD_wg0
PostDown = iptables -F WIREGUARD_wg0
PostDown = iptables -X WIREGUARD_wg0
```

Here is the state after `wg-quick down wg0`:

```
/etc/wireguard# iptables-save -c
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sat Sep  3 21:06:20 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
[42:2688] -A POSTROUTING -s 10.11.0.0/16 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
[122:7896] -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Sep  3 21:06:20 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sat Sep  3 21:06:20 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [33:3296]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [29:4668]
[4503:562848] -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Sep  3 21:06:20 2022
```

Then after `wg-quick up wg0`:

```
/etc/wireguard# iptables-save -c
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sat Sep  3 21:07:01 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 10.11.0.0/16 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
[42:2688] -A POSTROUTING -s 10.11.0.0/16 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
[122:7896] -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Sep  3 21:07:01 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sat Sep  3 21:07:01 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [15:1036]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [14:2920]
:WIREGUARD_wg0 - [0:0]
[4503:562848] -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -j WIREGUARD_wg0
[0:0] -A WIREGUARD_wg0 -s 10.11.0.2/32 -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A WIREGUARD_wg0 -s 10.11.0.3/32 -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A WIREGUARD_wg0 -s 10.11.0.4/32 -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A WIREGUARD_wg0 -s 10.11.0.5/32 -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A WIREGUARD_wg0 -s 10.11.0.6/32 -d 10.1.1.101/32 -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A WIREGUARD_wg0 -s 10.11.0.6/32 -d 10.1.1.151/32 -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A WIREGUARD_wg0 -s 10.11.0.6/32 -d 10.1.0.101/32 -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A WIREGUARD_wg0 -s 10.11.0.6/32 -i wg0 -j DROP
[0:0] -A WIREGUARD_wg0 -i wg0 -j DROP
[0:0] -A WIREGUARD_wg0 -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Sep  3 21:07:01 2022
```

Can anyone suggest what I've missed?
Many thanks.
Paul.

Comment: What does the rest of your iptables ruleset look like?

Comment: There's no PostDown matching PostUp. Chances are previous attempts were not cleaned up and do allow this client. So, asking concretely what user1686 asked, please provide the output of: `iptables-save -c`

Comment: A sorry... I do have the PostDown to perform cleanup, but you are right - it could be some left over rules. Adding the extra info...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like user1686 and A. B suspected, you have an old rule that's accepting all traffic coming in the `wg0` interface -- the first rule in your `FORWARD` chain, before the jump to your `WIREGUARD_wg0` chain:

```
[4503:562848] -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
```

Delete it to allow the filtering in your `WIREGUARD_wg0` chain to take effect:

```
iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: That was it! It was being set in /etc/iptables/rules.v4. So I deleted it, then rebuilt that file using iptables-save. Its working perfectly now. Thank you.